# Privatize connection to SQL Anywhere 16 Database

Tags: tcp, database-connection, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

After connecting to the database with one computer, I am looking to disallow any other network connections. My first attempt was to modify the network database server properties (see image below) to remove the `-x tcpip` parameter which, according to the help screen one gets when running the `dbsrv16.exe` command, is for "-x : comma-separated list of network drivers to run (TCPIP)".

[image: Service Properties]

However, even without this argument, I was still able to connect from a different computer. Now I'm back to the drawing board but have not a clue another possible way to accomplish my goal. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: It's not clear from the OP if the objective is to block all other users (ie, turn this into a single user system) or just block other login attempts for a given login.  The former of course can be dangerous if the implemented logic has a bug that keeps anyone from logging in (eg, to fix the logic).

If this was SAP/Sybase ASE I'd probably look at creating a login trigger that would disallow a secondary login.

Since this is SAP/Sybase SQL Anywhere, and I couldn't find any references to login triggers (though I didn't really look **that** hard), I'm wondering if it might be possible to:

- [create an event based on event_type = CONNECT](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/create-event-statement.html)
- if the event sees you're already logged in then don't allow the connection to continue (not sure programmatically how to do this; is there a disconnect() function call? or perhaps you could issue a [drop connection statement](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/drop-connection-statement.html) on the current connection?)

As I've already mentioned, this could be dangerous if there's a logic flaw in the event that disallows anyone from logging in. [I have no idea if there would be a way to disable the event from outside of SQLAnywhere, or if some logins could be exempted from CONNECT-based events ... ???]